# Why this Powershell code is not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I've this simple piece of code which is supposed to stop the timer at 10s and display the duration.

```
$StopWatch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$StopWatch.Start()
 while ($StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds -eq "10")
        {
            $StopWatch.Stop()
            $StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds
        }
```

The problem is when i run this via ISE its not stopping at 10s, it'll continue to run rather doing what it is supposed to do. I tried this with `If else` that also didn't work out.

What am i missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing the while loop wrong. It will only loop WHILE the timer is at 10 seconds, otherwise it just skips it.
What I think you are after is below. Code self explanatory. `Do` nothing `Until` condition.

```
$StopWatch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$StopWatch.Start()

Do{}
Until($StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds -eq "10")
$StopWatch.Stop()
$StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds
```

You could also do

```
$StopWatch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$StopWatch.Start()

# Notice the -ne (not equals)
While($StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds -ne "10") {}
$StopWatch.Stop()
$StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds
```